# Share file blocks between two files

Tags: windows, ntfs

I would like to create a copy of a file without using aditional disk space for the data, similar to what a hardlink would do.

However I would like this data to have CoW (copy on write) behaviour at the block/extent level, so only modified blocks/extents of data are actually written to disk, thus minimizing disk usage. I'm also trying to minimize the amount of I/O I'm doing by this.

The files are relatively large compared to the size of the differences between them, so copying the files and relying on mechanisms such as deduplication later would be a huge waste of resources.

An external application which I can't modify must be able to read the files in the format they are in, so alternatives that modify the contents of the files are unusable in my scenario.

No idea if this is possible on NTFS at the moment and my searches have not turned up anything useful, might be that I'm using the wrong terminology.

Comment: With NTFS, this would likely be accomplished through "reparse points" and a matching filesystem filter driver.

Answer (score 1):

You are perhaps looking for [Data Deduplication API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/_dedup/).
It cannot be done at the NTFS level, at least, without a filter driver.
Apart from that, you can use the [Remote Differential Compression API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/_rdc/) to do it manually. My [FileSnap](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1209648/FileSnap-A-Windows-library-for-differential-file-s) tool does exactly that.

Comment: am I wrong in assuming this would require an initial actual copy before deduplication, guess I should've mentioned in the question, I'm also looking to minimize the time doing I/O operations, totally appreciate the links though, having a look now

Comment: Why your I/O operations will be a problem?

Comment: I'm looking at very large files so copying them before deduplication would make my application horribly slower than being able to just declare that an extent belongs to two files. Also the differences are relatively minor compared to file size.

Comment: In that case you should implement manually part-like saving (like video/audio apps etc)

Comment: Thanks, I either did not understand completely the last statement or that would be insufficient, I have to use a specific format for the files and partial data would be useless due to how the data is interpreted, will move the comments to the question to clarify things for others.

Comment: I mean, work with links to the data, not the data itself.

Comment: If these links to the data can be made from another file so the filesystem knows directly how to read the contents of it as a single file can you point me to the api which creates them? And also add it to your answer cause that seems like what I'm looking for.

Comment: It cannot be done automatically at the filesystem level. You have to implement it manually. The RDC api I posted is one solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195203/discussion-between-xception-and-michael-chourdakis).